# ASP Chart Line Theme

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, series

I'm using chart helper on an mvc project but the line chart looks weird or doesn't looks like i want. I've been searching about this subject and the only thing I can find its the charttheme but only one example with series.  I'm including this, which is the only example i found about series on chart theme.

Series Name="Default" *Template*="All" BorderWidth="3" IsValueShownAsLabel="True"

I want to put this dot on the values instead of the numbers. I think the solution must be on "series" because the chart helper doesn't has many options but I can't find what other properties this series has. I have 2 images to upload but I can't because I need more reputation, I will try to update this if I get the reputation needed.

Comment: I answer to my self, what I was looking for its MarkerStyle=""Circle"" MarkerSize=""20"" , this goes on series label of the theme